# Proper permissions for Laravel project in /var/www/html

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I want to create a Laravel project in `/var/www/html` using `composer`.
Since `composer` won't allow you to run as root, I can make a directory and give it all the permissions `777` but I don't think that's a good idea.

So I was wondering what permissions shall I give to my new project folder so I can work with it?

Comment: Any specific reasons to create the project in that folder precisely? You can also create the folder anywhere else and then create a symlink for it  in /var/www/html

Comment: No reason at all. All my web projects are in /var/www/ and I always have a problem with permissions in `/var/www/` directory and I couldn't find anything online specifically about that. So I thought someone will clear it here for me.

Comment: Only root can write to `/var/www/html` and it's not a good idea to mess with the permissions of it. The best thing to do is what Raju has suggested which is to create a directory elsewhere to which `composer` can read, write, and execute and everyone else can read and traverse and then make a symlink to it in `/var/www/html`.

Comment: I did exactly what he suggested, but I ended up with creating some other problem in Virtual host. Apparently, the Virtualhost can't see that symlink from `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run composer as webserver user, who, I assume, owns the directory?

Something like:

```
sudo -u username command
```

in this case,

```
sudo -u [webserver_user] composer
```

that should do the trick.